# Ionic - svg does not appear

Tags: android, cordova, svg, ionic-framework, ionic2

I made the application build of the ionic 2 sidemenu, however the svg appears in the Chrome but svg does not appear in Android after generate the file android-debug.apk:

[image]

Follow the commands I used:

`npm install -g ionic cordova
ionic start myApp --v2 sidemenu
ionic platform add android
ionic build android`

**/myApp/src/pages/page1/page1.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>Page One</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>
    <img src="../../assets/img/myapp.svg" alt="">
    <p>
        If you get lost, the
        <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will show you the way.
    </p>
    <button ion-button secondary menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button>
</ion-content>
```

Could you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it is because you use the wrong path, remember when you build an app, you have this:

[image]

So the path is need to be `"./assets/img/myapp.svg"` intread `"../../assets/img/myapp.svg"` , because in a compiled app you are in the root , it's as if you are loading evething in the index.html file, and it's also works in the browser

Comment: Just /assets/img/myapp.svg (no period) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open your apk with a zip tool and check if apk contains image that you give. If so make sure your relative path points image.

Good luck

Comment: The svg file is on the following path`/android-debug.apk/assets/www/assets/img/`. If I swap the svg file for a png it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem that SVG format would not display in ionic 2 on build. 
My solution is that you need to put svg files into right assets folder, path to that folder is "./assets/img/[file_name]" like JoxieMedina explained why, and I used original html img tag instead of ionic ion-img because ion-img have some styling on default. If you are using ion-img then you will probably need to define width and/or height of an ion-img element to make it visible. Plus, in both cases, with img or ion-img element, I needed to put "backgroun-color: transparent" and define mime type type="image/svg+xml" to make it work.
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on HTML I use `assets/path/to/file`, as using other combinations did not work on Android.

Another reason that it might not work for some is due to path/filename case. I was requesting `MyFile.svg` but the file was actually `myfile.svg`.