# Ionic 3 background-image svg not appering in Ionic View

Tags: svg, ionic3, ionic-view

I'm developing an App using Ionic 2. Right now, I've this style:

```
ion-content {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/orange-background.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 101%;
}
```

When I `ionic serve` this works fine, but when I upload a new version to Ionic View channel, this example doesn't work neither any example of `background-image` with an `.svg`.

I already tried [Ionic - svg does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40960428/ionic-svg-does-not-appear) but didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

## Edit 1

I already tried this url in `background-image`:

```
assets/images/orange-background.svg
/assets/images/orange-background.svg
../assets/images/orange-background.svg
./assets/images/orange-background.svg
```

None of this worked :'(

## Edit 2

I just discovered that this problem only happens on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the url is incorrect. In the .css files: `url ('../assets/images/orange-background.svg')`.

In other case, did you make the difference: In Whindows an `image.SVG` will works when you test the app in a browser but wont in Linux (Also Android). It seems that an `image.SVG` is the same as `image.svg` in windows.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this didn't worked. I added an edit with all url I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I realized that the file was called **"Background.svg"**, and on my css I had:

`background-image: url("../assets/imgs/background.svg");`

Once I changed the file name to **"background.svg"** the problem was fixed.